# Show that there exists open set $O_n\subset [0,1]$ for all $n\in N$ such that $\overline{O_n}=[0,1]$ and $m^*(\cap_{n=1}^\infty O_n)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, baire-category

Show that there exists open set $O_n\subset [0,1]$ for all $n\in N$ such that $\overline{O_n}=[0,1]$ and $m^*(\cap_{n=1}^\infty O_n)=0$.

My work-

I feel like there is NO such a set. Because, by he Baire category theorem, intersection of dense open sets is not empty. This follows, $m^*(\cap_{n=1}^\infty O_n)\neq0$.

Or else, $\cap_{n=1}^\infty O_n$ should be a countable set. Could you help me to find such a set. Hint also would be nice.

Here $m^*$ is the outer measure.

Comment: Note: a measure zero set need not be empty.  And need not be countable.  Kavi's answer is probably found in every textbook on Lebesgue integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(r_n)$ be an ennumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. For each $k$ let $I_{kn}$ be the interval $(r_n-\frac 1 {2^{n+k}},r_n+\frac 1 {2^{n+k}})$. Let $O_k=\bigcup_n I_{kn}$. Check that this sequence has the required properties.

Comment: Hello @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you for the example but I have a little concern., Every $O_k$ is equals to $[0,1]$. Isn't it?. Then the intersection would not be rationals. take any $y\in [0,1]$ then no matter where you take the $y$ we can put it in to some ball in $O_k$ since rationals are dense, we can find rational very close to $y$. So, every time $O_k$ gives us the $[0,1]$. What would be your thought on this?

Comment: @ShanOH No, it is not true that $O_k=[0,1]$. That may seem intuitively right but the measure of $O_k$ is atmost $\frac  1 {2^{k}}$.